Replace Data in a Table in Snowflake with new data
Would like to know how to write a query to replace all the data within a table with fresh data, from an excel workbook. I am currently doing this line by line basically; insert into and delete from, but hoping there is a way to do it all at once. Very new to all things SQL and Snowflake, so forgive my simplicity in my request.
Again very much a beginner to anything and all sql and snowflake, please keep that in mind if deciding to respond, which you do not have too, thanks in advance.
When I want to delete account or accounts:
delete from "TABLE" where ACCT in (123,456,789);
When I want to add account or accounts:
insert into "TABLE" where (ACCT, NAME, TIER) values (123,'Acct Name','Tier Name;);
Instead of doing either, is there a way to clear the table & upload fresh data instead of doing it that way.
My table consist of three columns.

What do you mean? Do you want to delete all rows from your table and then insert all rows from another table? Please describe more detailed what you want to do.

Please clarify what you mean by replace an entire table. Like you just want to DELETE the data in the table and then INSERT new data, not actually remove the table from existence (aka DROP) and then recreate it. Please also share what you mean by "the manual way" and "adding and/or removing certain values manually". There is only SQL that you write and submit. Please try to share examples of what you are doing and what you want to do and avoid making up terms.

@JonasMetzler Yes basically replace all the data with a fresh data, its a table that contains the following columns: KUNNR_AG, CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_TIER. Currently when i want to add or delete a customer i use a query insert into or delete from.

@JNevill yes delete the data in the table and insert new data, not remove the table from existences (my title doesn't say delete). I'm new to all of this hence why i may referring to things in simple terms so apologies if you do not pick up what i mean, i am happy to wait for others to respond at my level.

@Kima Please don't write comments to improve your question or to add further information, but edit your question. You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Here's how to delete and insert data from/into a table: https://dbfiddle.uk/i3rw0Gxg If this is not sufficient for you, you need to tell us what you want to know.

Can you share an example of the INSERT or UPDATE statements (in the question, using Edit button) you submit to make these manual changes? I'm afraid there just isn't enough info here to guide you to a better solution. It might help to share sample data that is in this table, examples of statements you are currently submitting, and what your desired result would be (a bulk delete/insert, or what-have-you). No worries on the wrong terminology. I know it's frustrating to be starting out. Best to just use a lot of examples to describe or be very verbose.

If you want to replace the existing data in a table with a new set of data then just use INSERT OVERWRITE... e.g.
insert overwrite into "TABLE" (ACCT, NAME, TIER) 
values 
(123,'Acct Name','Tier Name');


Follow these steps if you want to delete everything in a table and replace it with data in an Excel file in Snowsight (new Snowflake), not Snowflake Classic:

Save the Excel file as a CSV
Execute TRUNCATE TABLE_NAME; which removes all rows in TABLE_NAME.
From the main page, open the Databases side menu, find the table, and click on it to open it.
On the top-right there is a blue button called Load Data. Go through the steps in Load Data to insert data from your CSV file and load its contents to the table. Note that the data appends rather than replaces, hence step 2.

